# Which are the reasons why pg_stats_all_table values might reset on a database?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, pg-stat-statements

I have read the PostgreSLQ [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-STATS-SETUP:%7E:text=28.2.1.-,Statistics%20Collection%20Configuration,-Since%20collection%20of) and it states that these conditions might reset the statistics' collection values:

- Immediate Shutdown of the database
- Server Crash (where the db is hosted)
- Manual resetting with SELECT pg_stat_statements_reset();
- Point-in-time recovery

I already made sure that the instace did not face a shutdown or crash and I did not manually reset the values with that query.

- What could other reasons might trigger the values reset?

**Further questions**

- Could a [backup](https://github.com/MBmousavi/PostgreSQL-Point-In-Time-Recovery) mess up these values as well?
- How could I throubleshoot this?

Comment: It's just a recovery or manual reset that would reset the statistics. Never had any issues with this. I would start to log every query and analyse the query log, there could be a rogue process requesting a reset. On the other hand, are you really using PostgreSQL 9.5 ? That version unsupported for 2 or 3 years, you might have found a bug in that version. Upgrade to a recent version, version 14 or so.

Comment: I am using 9.6, there a typo on the tags. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Same issue, 9.6 is also EOL.

Comment: I'd say the best bet is, that someone else did run `pg_stat_statements_reset()` manually.

Comment: 'already made sure that the instace did not face a shutdown or crash'. How did you do that?